# Deleting a node, that doesn't have the highest priority, from a priority queue

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, priority-queue

I am working on a project where we simulate the proccess of a restaurant.

We have 3 kinds of orders: Normal, Vegan and VIP orders.

For both the normal and the vegan orders, first come first serve, however, we should follow another service criteria concerning the vip orders.

We should develop a priority equation whose parameters are some information about the order, then the order with the highest priority (value) obtained from the priority equation should be served first.

So we decided to store the waiting vip orders in a priority queue, where we will enqueue the vip orders based on the value obtained from the priority equation and when we dequeue, the vip order with the highest priority is returned to be then transfered to a service list and continue the simulation.

We didn't notice a special case where a vip order that doesn't have the highest priority should be dequeued from the priority queue. Is there is any way to delete a node; which doesn't have the highest priority, from the priority queue, or we will have to change the data structure we store the vip orders in, from priority queue to a linked list?

Comment: Can you add links on your priority queue implementation?

Comment: A priority queue is an *abstract* data type that does not provide a remove-not-first method.  You may be able to do it with your specific implementation, but you haven't told us what that is.  Probably, though, you should just fix the priority equation.

Comment: It really depends on the priority queue implementation. For some, the answer is yes. For others, no. But you'll have to provide information about which implementation you're using before we can say for sure.